# jquery pan a large image within small div container using buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi there I need to an interactive element using a large image. This image sized 1000x1000 pixel with simple imagery will contain several questions with yes or no. What I want to do is place this image within a small div (say 500x300) with hidden overflow and add hotspots on the image for the yes/no option. What I want is when the user clicks yes, then the hotspot link pans to specific x/y coordinates of the same large image. Viewer will only see within the 500x300 window. So on and so forth. Is this possible? It seems so simple yet only option I can find is the pan by mouse option or iframe option with complicated divs and anchors. I'm not an expert in java/jquery but would love to find a script that is adaptable. Please help!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just make the large image `position: relative;` and then you can modify it's `left` and `top` to move it.

Comment: Please, submit some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css transitions for animation. Set up the positions you want the buttons to move the image around to in the image using a series of javascript objects. Then, set up your anchors, text, etc using absolute positioning on top of the image inside of a div container. Finally, add a click action in jQuery to assign your different positions to the top and left css of that container.

The end result, then, will be that you click an anchor, the left and top positions are assigned to the container via css in jQuery, and the transitions will slide the image around with the anchors.

[I set up a fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wlanni/p2kkhz1z/)

Here's the html from the fiddle:

```
<div id="window">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/1f/Kill_The_Lights_1000x1000.jpg" id="image">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="city" href="#">City</a></li>
            <li><a id="bottom" href="#">Bottom</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#window {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#window a {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
#city {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
#bottom {
    top: 220px;
    left: 220px;
}
#container {
    -webkit-transition:left 2s, top 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    transition:left 2s, top 2s, transform 2s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Here's some javascript to give an example of setting up the positions as objects.

```
var city = {
    top: -200,
    left: -200
};
var bottom = {
    top: -700,
    left: -100
}

$('a').click(function() {
    var t = this.id;
    var c = $('#container');
    if (typeof eval(t) !== 'undefined') {
        c.css({
            'top': eval(t).top,
            'left': eval(t).left
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounded fun so I made a custom solution real quick. Demo here: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/megewisazu/2/edit?js,output)

It's heavily reliant on the proper CSS, so check that in the bin, but here's the JS part:

```
var choice = document.querySelectorAll('.choice'),
    image  = document.getElementById('image')

for ( var i=0; i<choice.length; i++) {
  choice[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    var x = this.dataset['x'],
        y = this.dataset['y'];

    image.style.top = '-'+y+'px';
    image.style.left = '-'+x+'px';

  })  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elzi. Amazed that without any java knowledge this seems to make sense! :) I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4o27mgw/) with a demo image from where you could proceed.

HTML:

```
<div class="imgHolder">
  <div class="hotspot one">Click</div>
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgHolder {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
 }
 .hotspot.one {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  padding:2px;
  background-color:#fff;
  left:10px;
}
.hotspot:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
img {
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".hotspot").on("click", function () {
 $("img").animate({
    "right": "+=100px"
 });
});
```

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You could e.g. fade hotspots in and out on specific positions and use `animate()` to move to the next hotspot.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. I will try this out. Java looks like a monster to learn but thank god for jQuery scripts and html/css being a bit less intimating. However does this only move at a certain notch? Am I free to make each click unique based on their response?